# Function to build a vector with dynamic substring in items

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to build a function that allows me to dynamically make a vector called `independent_vars`. This is my attempt so far:

```
independent_vars_fcn <- function(.x){

    substring <- enquo(.x) 

    Hmisc::Cs(
        paste0("size_", !! substring, "_s"),
        paste0("color_", !! substring, "_s"),
        paste0("shape_", !! substring, "_s"),
        paste0("softness_", !! substring, "_s"),
        paste0("brightness_", !! substring, "_s"),
        paste0("comfort_", !! substring, "_s"))
    
}
```

However, when I try to call this function it is not evaluating `substring`. E.g.

```
independent_vars_fcn("office")
'paste0("size_", !!substring, "_s")''paste0("color_", !!substring, "_s")''paste0("shape_", !!substring, "_s")''paste0("softness_", !!substring, "_s")''paste0("brightness_", !!substring, "_s")''paste0("comfort_", !!substring, "_s")'
```

Where I actually want it to look like this:

```
'size_office_s', 'color_office_s', 'shape_office_s', 'softness_office_s', 'brightness_office_s', 'comfort_office_s'
```

Note i'm using `Hmisc::Cs()` instead of regular `c()` because I want to pass the vector into `reformulate` to build an equation and that requires each item in the vector is wrapped in quotes. Because I have many `substring`s it'd be good to be able to make the `independent_vars_fcn` once and then feed it into `reformulate` like so:

```
reformulate(c(independent_vars_fcn("office")), "dependent_var_example_1")
reformulate(c(independent_vars_fcn("kitchen")), "dependent_var_example_2")
etc...
```

I assume i'm getting the tidy evaluation wrong somehow. Can someone see where i'm going wrong here?

I've also tried this if helpful, but it produces the same output:

```
independent_vars_fcn <- function(.x){

    Hmisc::Cs(
        paste0("size_", .x, "_s"),
        paste0("color_", .x, "_s"),
        paste0("shape_", .x, "_s"),
        paste0("softness_", .x, "_s"),
        paste0("brightness_", .x, "_s"),
        paste0("comfort_", .x, "_s"))
    
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `c()` in the function, and then use `reformulate(independent_vars_fcn("office"), "dependent_var_example_1")`?

Comment: I've put in as a answer with an explanation.. You can use Hmisc as @akrun has shown. I just wanted to answer the portion of your post that implied that it was required here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Hmisc as @akrun has shown.  However, I wanted to respond to your comment about needing to use it. I think not necessary. Just use `c()` in your function.

```
independent_vars_fcn <- function(.x) {
  c(
    paste0("size_", .x, "_s"),
    paste0("color_", .x, "_s"),
    paste0("shape_", .x, "_s"),
    paste0("softness_", .x, "_s"),
    paste0("brightness_", .x, "_s"),
    paste0("comfort_", .x, "_s")
  )
}

reformulate(independent_vars_fcn("office"),"dependent_var_example_1")
```

Output:

```
dependent_var_example_1 ~ size_office_s + color_office_s + shape_office_s + 
    softness_office_s + brightness_office_s + comfort_office_s
```

Its probably better to put a parameter in the function so that you can more easily change the independent variables, like this:

```
independent_vars_fcn <- function(.x, keys = c("size", "color", "shape", "softness", "brightness", "comfort")) {
  sapply(keys, \(k) paste0(k,"_", .x, "_s"))
}

reformulate(independent_vars_fcn("office"),"dependent_var_example_1")
```

Output:

```
dependent_var_example_1 ~ size_office_s + color_office_s + shape_office_s + 
    softness_office_s + brightness_office_s + comfort_office_s
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for sharing. I think it's a better answer as it doesn't depend on any external packages (even though `Hmisc` is a very popular one)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `sprintf` approach.

```
independent_vars_fcn <- \(.x) {
  pfx <- c('size', 'color', 'shape', 'softness', 'brightness', 'comfort')
  unname(vapply(pfx, \(x, y) sprintf('%s_%s_s', x, y), character(1L), .x))
}

independent_vars_fcn('office')
# [1] "size_office_s"       "color_office_s"      "shape_office_s"      "softness_office_s"  
# [5] "brightness_office_s" "comfort_office_s"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `do.call` for the posted issue for `Hmisc::Cs`

```
 independent_vars_fcn <- function(.x)
      {
            do.call(Hmisc::Cs, 
                list(paste0("size_", .x, "_s"),
                paste0("color_", .x, "_s"),
                paste0("shape_", .x, "_s"),
                paste0("softness_", .x, "_s"),
                paste0("brightness_", .x, "_s"),
                paste0("comfort_", .x, "_s")))
    
        }
```

-testing

```
> independent_vars_fcn("office")
[1] "size_office_s"       "color_office_s"      "shape_office_s" 
[4] "softness_office_s"   "brightness_office_s" "comfort_office_s"
```